# How can alias join table all columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have staff table

```
    id  staff_id  first_name  last_name
------  --------  ----------  ---------
```

and actor table

```
    id  staff_id  first_name  last_name
------  --------  ----------  ---------
```

For join I know I can use select alias like this

```
SELECT 
  staff.*,
  actor.id AS actor_id,
  actor.first_name AS actor_first_name,
  actor.last_name AS actor_last_name
```

And get result like

```
    id  first_name  last_name  actor_id  actor_first_name  actor_last_name  
------  ----------  ---------  --------  ----------------  -----------------
```

But for each column I use

```
  actor.col AS actor_col
```

How Can I do it more general way. For example if I have 40 or more column I did not want for each column name write alias

Comment: There is no more general way. And  don't try to "automate" your queries. It is just like writing good code - don't be afraid of a little typing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL aliases are used to give a table, or a column in a table, a temporary name.

Aliases are often used to make column names more readable.

An alias only exists for the duration of the query.

So here you have a long table where you have more than 40 column which is pretty boring for you in that case you can try several things like

> column which isn't same-named you can ignore alias name before them but where names are identical you must use the alias otherwise those will be ambiguous.
>
> there is another way, you can use the view instead of a table, where you will create a new clone of your table with a different name so you don't have to write them over and over.

Check basic syntax here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp